# Who can I create a Share Android App to send to my clients or colleagues? Like iOS AdHoc

Tags: android, share, apk, adhoc

I'm over an Android App for a client, eventually I want to show him some demo, but he doesn't have the IDE, so I'm thinking to send him an APK ... In iOS it's pretty easy through AdHoc and the Mobile ID...

I just want to send him an APK for him to install in his phone... (Not Android Market YET)

How can I do this on Android?

Thanks!

Comment: send to gmail and click attachment to install it on the android phone

Answer (score 0):

You could host the apk file on a web server and then share the url with your friends.
When they open the url on there android phones they will be prompted by the browser about whether they want to install the apk.

Answer (score 0):

Just send him the APK from your bin folder :) He can easily install it if sent to his gMail account, he only has to click on the atachment in his gmail client. Othervise, he will need a file manager.

In both cases he will need to set Authorize unsigned apps on his phone.